# Pass query parameter into WooCommerce checkout upon redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Feel like I must be missing something pretty obvious here – looking for any help you can provide.

**Helpful Background:**

- Wordpress: 5.7.2
- WooCommerce: 5.4.1
- Standard shop page
- Standard checkout page

**Scenario:**

My shop page has a custom query parameter in the url (e.g. `?model=macbook`). I'm hoping to pass that query parameter & value on to the redirected checkout url as well. So that it would read – `example.com/checkout/?model=macbook`.

I am currently using the following code in my child theme's functions.php. This handles the redirect to checkout add-to-cart action no problem but my php noobie-ness  cannot figure out how to properly use the add_query_arg to complete the checkout url.

```
    // Checkout Redirect
    add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'this_add_to_cart_redirect');
    function this_add_to_cart_redirect() {
     global $woocommerce;
     $checkout_url = wc_get_checkout_url();
     return $checkout_url;
    }
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
// Checkout Redirect
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'this_add_to_cart_redirect' );
function this_add_to_cart_redirect() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $checkout_url = add_query_arg( [
        'model' => 'macbook',
    ], wc_get_checkout_url() );

    return $checkout_url;
}
```

Comment: You sir, are awesome. Is there a way for that value to be dynamic though? So for example user 'A' might have model=XYZ and user 'B' might have model=ABC


@Mr.Jo The shop page url would contain the proper dynamic value for the user session – I just need to grab that value and pass it into the model parameter for the checkout redirect.

Comment: @Josh sure you can make it dynamic depending on some values. I don't see any given values in your question so I can not help here.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Jo – The 'model' parameter is actually a dynamic field that is originally populated by the user submitting a form.  The value is already passed through to the shop page upon form submission. I'd like to pass it through again upon checkout redirect. So ideally, the add_to_cart_redirect looks at the custom value for parameter key 'model' (e.g. model=XYZ) in the current url string and appends that to the add-to-cart redirect url at checkout (eg. .../checkout?model=XYZ)

Comment: In this case you can get it with `$_POST` or `$_GET` in PHP and pass it as value to the query function instead of macbook: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_post.asp https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_get.asp